# Opening a file using PHP also inserts everything thats echoed

Tags: php, file, output

I'm trying to open a file using PHP. The thing is that the file saves correctly on the server, but when I want to open via PHP, so the user can download/view it, it also shows the other echos that are done in the code. If someone has an idea it would mean a big help to me.

This is my code:

```
<?php

echo"<form method='post'><p>"; 

foreach ($ini_array as $section => $value){ 

    if ($section == 'FILE') {   // Ignorar la $section de pos 0 donde estan los datos del [FILE]
        continue;
    }

    if ($ini_array[$section]['Edit'] == false) { 
        $default_value_control = 'disabled';
    }else{
        $default_value_control = '';
    }

    echo
    "<div class='container'><input type=".$ini_array[$section]['Obj']." name='".$section."' value='".$ini_array[$section]['Value']."' ".$default_value_control. ">".$ini_array[$section]['Desc']."</div><div class='tooltip'>?<span class='tooltiptext'>".$ini_array[$section]['Help']."</span></div> <br>";
}

if (isset($_POST['ExecCmd'])){
    try{
        ini_set("display_errors", 0); 
        $cmd=$ini_array['FILE']['Path']." ";
        foreach ($ini_array as $section => $value){
            $manualinput=$_POST[$section];
            if (!empty($manualinput)){
               $cmd.=" ".$ini_array[$section]['Flag']." ".$manualinput;
            }
        }
    }
    finally { ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    }
        $myfile = fopen("output.csv", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        //echo $cmd;
        $command = escapeshellcmd($cmd); 
        $output = shell_exec($command);
        echo $output;       

        fwrite($myfile, $output);
        fclose($myfile);

        $file_url = 'output.csv';
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
        readfile($file_url);

}

echo "<button name='ExecCmd'>Execute</button></p></form>";

?>
```

Comment: Do you have an opening `<?php` tag before the code? Do you have PHP server running?

Comment: _“it also shows the PHP code on the page”_ - where? Which page? What code? And show _proper_ code please. Right now we have no idea what `$cmd` contains, and therefor what you are doing in the shell.

Comment: I do have a server runing and I open correctly the tags for php. $cmd contains a python file that executes through the terminal. The output comes fine, and if I open manually the file with a text editor, I see only the output that i want. But, when I try to download/open the file from my PHP, it also prints the code PHP of my page on the output file. Thats what i meant.

Comment: Oh, I'm getting it now. My bad. The problem is that its printing some echos with HTML code that i'm doing with PHP. I dont know why its only showing when I want to download/view the file through PHP. Because if I open it manually, going to the directory and using some editor to open it, it shows the correct output.

Comment: I have updated my code so now it shows everything I want to do

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I did was to generate a new echo with a link if the submit button is pressed. That way it redirects to a new page that has the readfile($file_url); and opens the previously saved file without the extra echoed items.

```
if (isset($_POST['EjecutarCmd'])){
... all the above ...
echo "<a href='testoutputfile.php' target='_blank'>Download Report</a>";
}
```

So I moved all of this to this new "testoutputfile.php".

```
<?php
    $file_url = 'output.csv';
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
    readfile($file_url);
?>
```

UPDATE:

Then, I wanted the new window to be closed when the PHP code executes. There's no way to do it without using JavaScript, so I needed to use another echo to insert a JavaScript code. Finnaly I used the ob_start(); and ob_end_clean(); functions to control the buffer of the outputs.

So I ended with this on the new page "testoutputfile.php".

```
<?php
 $file_url = 'output.csv';
 header('Content-Type: text/csv');
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
 header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
 readfile($file_url);
 ob_start();
 echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
 ob_end_clean();
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should split the function into two different php file.
A file to download specfic file.
B file to echo proper info.

So, if you want download, request A file; if you need to echo some info, request B.

For pattern design is also a better practice.

_________below show be ignored___________

header('Content-Type: text/csv');

For more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types

In my case, these code worked fine when using chrome to visit the page.

> But, when I try to download/open the file from my PHP, it also prints the code PHP of my page on the output file. Thats what i meant.

This is another question ~~!

Comment: Yes, maybe that's something to correct but doesn't solve the issue. Thank you tho.